# KOHANA Themes - how to set theme in K3

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-3.2

dudes.

I hope this question is not a repost.

I'm newbie on Kohana. I'm working in a system made by other guy.

I need to understand how to set the theme but I can't find anything here nor google.
I found that in some systems is set a cookie called theme. But I don't know where to set this cookie.

Could someone tell how to set themes in Kohana?

Thank you all, dudes.

JuanMatias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kohana is a framework to develop applications from scratch - it doesn't come with any themes like Drupal or WordPress. If what you are looking for are templates, you can use the `Controller_Template` base class. Just make your controllers extend it:

```
class Controller_Extends extends Controller_Template
```

Then set the template body using something like:

```
$this->template->content = $content;
```

Finally, create the template file in `application/views/template.php`:

```
<!-- Here goes the header -->
if (isset($content)) echo "<div id='content'>$content</div>";
<!-- Here goes the footer -->
```

Comment: Laurent, thanks. As I said I'm a newbie. I was talking about the themes, those ones in asset/admin/css/themes. I'm able to change it forcing the $theme var just before my template load the styles (I foun this line in my admin.php layout: "    <?php echo Html::style("assets/admin/css/themes/{$theme}/style.css") ?>"). Thanks again and sorry for my rookie question.